# Tame abelian tensor categories

Tags: abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

In the article "Tannaka duality for geometric stacks" ([arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412266), see [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tannaka+duality+for+geometric+stacks) for a summary) Jacob Lurie introduced the notion of a *tame* abelian tensor category. An abelian tensor category is called tame if every short exact sequence $0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0$ with $M''$ flat remains exact after tensoring with an arbitrary object. Basically this means that flat objects behave in the usual way. For example it is easy to check that in a tame abelian tensor category every extension of flat objects is flat (Lemma 5.4).

**Question 1:** Do you know any further literature about tame abelian tensor categories?

**Question 2:** Can you give an explicit example of an abelian tensor category which is *not* tame? Jacob Lurie remarks that every abelian tensor category with enough flat objects is tame, because then we can define $Tor_1$ and use symmetry. So in particular, a counterexample does not have enough flat objects.
[Tom Goodwillie has given an example below]

**Question 3:** Can you give an example of a cocontinuous tensor functor between tame abelian tensor categories which is not tame?

Comment: What's a flat object?

Comment: Flat module: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module

Comment: Well it's an object $M$ such that the functor $M \otimes -$ is exact. See also Lurie's article for more definitions and background.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the definition: is the category of torsion abelian groups an example of an abelian tensor category? With $\otimes$ having its usual meaning? If so, then it seems that $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is flat (tensor product with anything is zero!) but the sequence

$0\to \mathbb Z/p \to \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\to 0$

does not remain exact when you tensor it with $\mathbb Z/p$.

EDIT: For a true example I need the $\otimes$ operation to have a unit object. You can artificially introduce a unit, but it won't help with this example, so first let me alter the example. Choose a domain $R$ that is a $\mathbb Q$-algebra and not a field. Let $K$ be the field of fractions. In the category of torsion $R$-modules $M\otimes (K/R)$ is always zero, and the sequence

$0\to R/fR \to K/fR\to K/R\to 0$

does not remain exact when tensored with $R/fR$. Now, to introduce a unit, consider the product of the category of $\mathbb Z$-modules and the category of torsion $R$-modules. Define

$(A,M)\otimes (A',M')=(A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}A',A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}M'\oplus A'\otimes_{\mathbb Z}M\oplus M\otimes_RM')$.

The object $(0,K/R)$ is flat (this uses that $K/R$ is a flat $\mathbb Z$-module), and the sequence

$0\to (0,R/fR) \to (0,K/fR)\to (0,K/R)\to 0$

does not remain exact when tensored with $(0,R/fR)$.

Comment: Thanks! This answers 2). [The definition of abelian tensor categories is given in the nlab article which I have linked, for example]

Comment: Hmm ... My example doesn't qualify because there is no unit object for $\otimes$.

Comment: I didn't see your edit. This example works :).